# PHP - parsing complicated XML with NameSpaces

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I'm guessing the NameSpaces are causing `simplexml_load_string` to not work, but I'm definitely not sure.

**log.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sns="http://soap.com/pbx">
   <env:Body>
      <sns:CDR>
         <PrimaryCallID>02v7b7c16v@12.123.123.12</PrimaryCallID>
         <CallID>d352f920@pbx</CallID>
         <From>"SMITH JOHN    " &lt;sip:11234567890@sub.domain.com:5060;user=phone&gt;</From>
         <To>&lt;sip:3216549870@111.111.111.111:5060;user=phone&gt;</To>
         <Direction>O</Direction>
         <Type>attendant</Type>
         <RemoteParty />
         <LocalParty />
         <TrunkName />

... more xml...

      </sns:CDR>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**parse.php**

```
<?php 
$string = "log.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
print_r($xml);
?>
```

I'm getting nothing back from the `print_r`
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

simplexml_load_string takes a string as an argument not a filename.
you're trying to load the string "log.xml" as a XML and that doesn't work
you can use this intead:

```
$filename = "log.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($filename));
print_r($xml);
```

Comment: Good point! Made the change, and now the result is: `SimpleXMLElement Object ( )`
I also switched to `simple_load_file()`, with the same result.

Comment: is the xml file in the same directory as the php file?

Comment: Yep, definitely is in the same directory

Comment: if you print the return of file_get_contents whats in there?

Comment: I get the same as I posted above. Well, in the browser the xml does get translated, but in the source it appears in it's xml format

Comment: have you checked the syntax of the XML file? also sometimes and XML object doesnt' print anything on screen unless you access a node directly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33019/discussion-between-coffeemonitor-and-stratton)